# Let $n$ be a positive integer and $S$ the set of points $(x,y)$ in the plane, where $x$ and $y$ are non-negative integers such that $x + y < n$.

Tags: combinatorics, problem-solving

Let $n$ be a positive integer and $S$ the set of points $(x,y)$ in the plane, where $x$ and $y$ are non-negative integers such that $x + y < n$. The points of $S$ are colored in red and blue so that if $(x, y)$ is red, then $(x', y')$ is red as long as $x'\leq x$ and $y'\leq y$. Let $A$ be the number of ways to choose $n$ blue points such that all their $x$-coordinates are different and let $B$ be the number of ways to choose $n$ blue points such that all their $y$-coordinates are different. Prove that $A = B$.

How one can set up a proof like this? I've tried but to me seems really hard...

Comment: How are the blue points determined?

Answer (score 1):

This is the first problem of the $2002$ IMO. You can find various solutions [here](http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h17336p118710)

Comment: Thanks! The problem was given by a friend of mine and I didn't know where to look...

Comment: No problem, you can also find a carefully written solution in page 8 of  this book (the author studied in my college). http://www.hexagon.edu.vn/images/resources/upload/dec3c0b23f6d5bffa9c661616b1658fd/problemsolvingmethods%20in%20combinatorics%20an%20approach%20to%20olympiad_1377958817.pdf

Comment: I do not know how to do it on iPhone interface :(