# Understanding the problem statement of IMO 2002 Problem $1$

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

$S$ is the set of all $(h, k)$ with $h, k$ non-negative integers such
that $h + k$ < $n$. Each element of $S$ is colored red or blue, so that if $(h, k)$
is red and $h_o ≤ h, k_o ≤ k$, then $(h_o, k_o$
) is also red. A type 1 subset of $S$ has
n blue elements with different first member and a type 2 subset of S has $n$
blue elements with different second member. Show that there are the same
number of type 1 and type 2 subsets.

I don’t quite understand how the problem work. I suspect that you have choose a point in the plane (x,y)such that $x+y\le n-1$, and then color all the points $(x_o,y_o)$ such that $x_o\le x, y_o\le y $ and then count how many lists that contains $n$ blue points that have different $x$ coordinate and do the same thing again but change it to the $y$ coordinate. Am I right.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1351555/let-n-be-a-positive-integer-and-s-the-set-of-points-x-y-in-the-plane-wh?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps an illustrative example would help. You need to show that for every $n\ge 1$, and for every valid coloring of $S$, the number of ways to choose $n$ blue elements with distinct first coordinates is equal to the number of ways to choose $n$ blue elements with distinct second coordinates. Below, I give two examples of colorings, one with $n=3$ and the other with $n=4$, together with the list of all the ways to select $n$ blue coordinates. As you can see, the number of ways to make both selections is the same; both ways have two selections in the first coloring, and both ways have four selections for the second coloring. You need to prove this always happens.

| Coloring | Selections with distinct first coordinates | Selections with distinct second coordinates |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $ \newcommand{\r}[1]{\bbox[pink, 2pt]{\mathsf #1}} \newcommand{\b}[1]{\bbox[cyan, 2pt]{\mathsf #1}} \begin{array}{ccc} \b{A}\\ \r B & \b C \\ \r D & \b E & \b F \end{array} $ | $\{\b A, \b C, \b F\}$ and $\{\b A, \b E, \b F\}$. | $\{\b A, \b C, \b F\}$ and $\{\b A, \b C, \b E\}$ |
| $ \newcommand{\r}[1]{\bbox[pink, 2pt]{\mathsf #1}} \newcommand{\b}[1]{\bbox[cyan, 2pt]{\mathsf #1}} \begin{array}{ccc} \b{A}\\ \b B & \b C &\\ \r D & \b E & \b F\\ \r G & \r H & \r I & \b J \end{array} $ | $\begin{array}{c} \{\b A, \b C, \b F, \b J\}\\ \{\b A, \b E, \b F,\b J\}\\ \{\b B, \b C, \b F, \b J\}\\ \{\b B, \b E, \b F,\b J\}\end{array}$ | $\begin{array}{c} \{\b A, \b C, \b F, \b J\}\\ \{\b A, \b C, \b E,\b J\}\\ \{\b A, \b B, \b F, \b J\}\\ \{\b A, \b B, \b E,\b J\}\end{array}$ |

Comment: What do you mean by a valid coloring? Because sometimes you can get that the number of blue point is less than $n$ so how can I deal with that?

Comment: @Yassir By a valid coloring, I mean that whenever $(h,k)$ is colored red and $h_0\le h$ and $k_0\le k$ then $(h_0,k_0)$ is red as well. If the number of blue points is less than $n$, then there are zero ways to make the selection in both cases, so the result is still true.